# Java: Keep getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException, can't figure out where I'm using an invalid index

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I've looked at a lot of answers and none of them seemed to apply (ex. i start my for loop at 0, instead of one which is a common mistake). This is a method used in an anagram word game. Please help me, I've been at this for five hours straight and I think I'm hallucinating from sleep deprivation.

EDIT: The error occurs at the line `ugh.remove(thing.charAt(i));`

```
public boolean anagramOfLetterSubset(String thing, ArrayList<Character> reference) {
    ArrayList<Character> ugh = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int h = 0; h < reference.size(); h++) {
        ugh.add(reference.get(h));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thing.length(); i++) { //cycles through the letters in the word
        for (int f = 0; f < reference.size(); f++) { //cycles through the characters in the reference arraylist
            if ((reference.get(f) == thing.charAt(i)) && (reference.indexOf(thing.charAt(i)) != -1)) { //sees if the letter and the character match
                ugh.remove(thing.charAt(i)); //removes first instance of character
            }
        }
    }
    if (ugh == reference)
        return false;  // change the value returned
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: The exception tells you the line number.

Comment: You should get a stacktrace that tells you in what line the exception occurs.

Comment: First step: read the exceptino stack trace. But you haven't posted it, though...

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: Note that `ugh == reference` will never be true, since they are distinct object instances .

Comment: `thing.charAt(i);` can return larger index then the number of elements in `ugh`

Comment: I believe that `remove(thing.charAt(i))` will call [`remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) rather than [`remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)). Try `remove((Character) thing.charAt(i))` instead.

Comment: @Oleg thing.charAt(i); returns a character, though.

Comment: Which is going to be widened to `int` as noted by @khelwood

Comment: @Oleg thank you, that was what I was missing!! Didn't realize it would widen to an int, that explains it

Comment: Dev note : instead of using a if / else condition at the end to return do `return (ugh == reference);`

Comment: @JérémyFerreira He can simplify it to `return false` see comment from Berger above

Answer (score 2):

`List` has two `remove` methods: [`remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)), which removes an element at a given index; and [`remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) which finds and removes a given object from the list.

If you call `remove(thing.charAt(i))`, the argument is a `char`. A `char` is not an object, but it can be widened to an integer, so it is `remove(int)` that gets called. The character will be taken to indicate an index in your list (hence the exception).

To call `remove(Object)` instead, try

```
ugh.remove((Character) thing.charAt(i));
```